# Cyanogenmod stopped being blue

Tags: cyanogenmod, themes

The icons changed to a green scheme instead of the normal blue scheme, and it persists even after reboot. The autocomplete text is yellow now, as is the browser loading bar.  What happened??

This screenshot is from a while ago, when I was using a different launcher, but it shows how the colours were until yesterday. (There's also some unrelated background corruption.)

[image: different launcher, blue icons]

Now the Wi-Fi and cell and messaging and browser icons are green:

[image: current launcher and green icons]

I tried reflashing the same version of CM7, and it's still green:

[image: ROM version]

I don't care too much about the color, but I don't know how this could have happened and wonder if it indicates some kind of corruption of the phone's Flash, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently themes on Cyanogenmod are controlled by an app called...  Theme Chooser.

I didn't even know they were customizable, and had never opened the app before (and I would expect such a thing to be in the Settings, not in an app).

Anyway, mine was on the "System" theme, which is green, and I can easily change it back to the "Cyanbread" theme, which is the blue one I am used to.

I don't know how or why it changed, but it's easy enough to fix once you learn where they are configured, and doesn't seem as big of a deal as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

The colours aren't the only difference. Your second screenshot also has a dark background to each shortcut's label, and a different graphic for the tray at the bottom. The combination of graphical changes to the launcher, changes to SystemUI, and different-coloured icons for system apps like the browser, makes me say the second screenshot is of a *different version* of Cyanogenmod, or a different ROM completely.

Could you or someone else have flashed a new ROM onto your phone? If you're not sure, go into the **Settings** app, click **About device** and read the version information on that screen.

Comment: Agree. It looks like the first screenshot is CM using Trebuchet launcher, and the second one is another ROM (with a different launcher).

Comment: Yes they are of different versions of the launcher,  but that's irrelevant.  Yesterday morning it looked like the bottom picture except with blue theme, later in the day it spontaneously changed to the bottom picture. I didn't have a screenshot of the Before of course, because I cannot predict the future. :)

Comment: Its not possible that someone could have flashed a new rom, I was holding the phone before and after it changed. In fact I reflashed the same rom and its still green.

Comment: @endolith I've taken the liberty of adding that important piece of information to your question.

Comment: @endolith Could you show use the About details? Does it still say CM?

Comment: @geffchang: It does, yes.  `CyanogenMod-7.2.0-vision`, as it's said for years.